# Reset Heroku Postgres database in run option of Travis deploy

Tags: postgresql, heroku, travis-ci

I'd like to reset my database and seed it with some default data after a successful deploy to Heroku using Travis CI.

The Travis docs say to put this kind of task in the 'run' option of the 'deploy' task in the .travis.yml file, e.g.:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: ...
  run:
    - "rake db:migrate"
    - restart
    - "rake cleanup"
```

'rake db:reset' doesn't work with Postgres because it has strict permissions. However, I can reset the db from the command line using 'heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL' (after getting the db url from 'heroku pg:info').

But how can I run this command from Travis after deploy? I've tried

```
run:
    - pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL
```

and

```
run:
    - "pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL"
```

and

```
run:
    - "heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL"
```

but the db is never reset. i either get 'bash: pg:reset: command not found' or 'bash: heroku: command not found'

Answer (score 0):

You need to remotely connect to your travis environment and install Heroku toolbelt from toolbelt.heroku.com and do `heroku login` to authenticate. That will install the heroku executable you need.

Answer (score 0):

The `run` command in the `deploy` section of your `.travis.yml` calls the command on your actual applications bash. Your second example `- "pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL"` is correct. However, this does not work work with your pg command, as the pg is part of the heroku toolbelt and is not installed on your heroku applications vm, and also is not installed on travis vm's by default. You could potentially install the heroku toolbelt on the travis-ci vm and call the command `heroku pg:reset` if you like though, and that would work.